# Can I run fsck or e2fsck when Linux file system is mounted?

Tags: command-line, fsck

I mean I'm already here right. If not, why?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No.

Do not run fsck on a live or mounted file system. [`fsck`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/fsck.ext2.8.html) is used to check and optionally repair a Linux file systems. Running `fsck` on a mounted filesystem can usually result in disk and/or data corruption.

---

**Outdated method (SysVinit/upstart based, Ubuntu before version 15.04):**

This will force a check on next boot:

`sudo touch /forcefsck`

So will this but it will also reboot the machine at the moment you hit enter:

`shutdown -rF now`

There are more ways (like telling the machine to go to `init 1` and then umount the partition/disc your want to check) but these 2 are the easiest.

---

**Nowadays (systemd based systems, Ubuntu 15.04 and later)** we can use

```
sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sdX
```

replace `sdX` by your partitions device name. 1 is the amount of boots for it to do a new filesystemcheck (so 1 is every time. 10 would check every 10 boots. 0 or -1 disables it).

So after the boot do

```
sudo tune2fs -c 0 /dev/sdX
```

to disable it.

Example:

```
rinzwind@discworld:~$ sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/nvme0n1p3
tune2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
Setting maximal mount count to 1
rinzwind@discworld:~$
```

Using it on a device with the wrong filesystem errors out:

```
inzwind@discworld:~$ sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/nvme0n1p1
tune2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p1 contains a vfat file system
```

(that is the /boot/EFI one ;) )

Comment: Also, don't try to get around this by running it read-only. The results from analyzing a moving target [cannot be trusted](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/fsck.ext2.8.html).

Comment: Good call ændrük

Comment: `sudo touch /forcefsck`  only works with the old SysVinit and early versions of Upstart, it won’t work with systemd