# Problem with 'sudo apt-get upgrade'

Tags: upgrade, apt, dpkg

When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, the following error arises:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice apport apt apt-transport-https apt-utils aptitude bash bash-completion bind9-host curl dbus dmsetup dnsutils icedtea-6-jre-cacao
  icedtea-6-jre-jamvm iptables isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common language-selector-common libaccountsservice0 libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12 libasound2
  libbind9-80 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libcups2 libcupsimage2 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libdbus-1-3 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdns81
  libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgnutls26 libisc83 libisccc80 libisccfg82
  liblwres80 libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient18 libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-1d libplymouth2 libservlet2.5-java libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.0.0
  libtiff4 libtomcat6-java libudev0 libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-xcb1 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb1 libxext6
  libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxml2 libxrender1 libxslt1.1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 linux-libc-dev multiarch-support
  mysql-client mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server nginx nginx-common nginx-full openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib openssh-client
  openssh-server openssl perl perl-base perl-modules plymouth plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text python-apport python-apt python-apt-common python-mysqldb
  python-paramiko python-problem-report rsyslog tomcat6 tomcat6-admin tomcat6-common tomcat6-docs tomcat6-examples udev
112 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/88.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 204 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar was killed by signal (Segmentation fault), core dumped
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.2-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.2-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get --reinstall install bash`, and it outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  bash-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bash
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 114 not upgraded.
Need to get 616 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 kB disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main bash i386 4.2-2ubuntu2.1 [616 kB]
Fetched 616 kB in 1s (591 kB/s)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar was killed by signal (Segmentation fault), core dumped
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.2-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.2-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My problem seems to be with the `bash` package as [alaa said](https://askubuntu.com/a/309697/22949).

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: I tried it but the problem still persists

Comment: Have you run a `fsck`? Could be corruption or physical damage.

Comment: do `sudo dpkg -a --configure`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the `bash` package that's in the cache. Here's what you can try:

1. Do `sudo apt-get clean`.
2. Do `sudo apt-get --reinstall install bash`
3. If it installs successfully, do `sudo apt-get update`, then do `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be: "apt-get install' (before)" --reinstall"? or does this not matter?      'sudo  aptitude apt-get install --reinstall bash'

Comment: @DnrDevil shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: did not work too

Comment: This fixes most problems with broken dependencies but if you read the output you see the OPs problem is not about broken dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this helps:

> sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

then this:

> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a broken dpkg system. Try this.

1. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried dozens of solutions I have found online but nothing worked. In the end, this is what fixed it for me:

`sudo touch /forcefsck`

`sudo shutdown -rF now`

As seen here: https://askubuntu.com/a/47974

Answer (score 0):

The `tar` binary file is corrupted and you can validate this by running:

```
tar --help
```

and you get `segmentation fault, core dumped.`
you should replace the `/bin/tar` binary with a healthy **tar** file from another host.