# dpkg took too long

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

i was running "sudo apt upgrade" but it was failed cus the vm turn off, so i tried to run upgrade again and it says i should run "sudo dpkg --configure -a", so i tried it didnt finish till i wait about 30 minutes, is it really that long?

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-92-generic
```

Comment: That is indeed the step that takes the longest for me. If you want to see which file it is stuck on you can run `sudo update-initramfs -u -v` separately

Comment: @DanielT its stuck here 

Adding module /lib/modules/5.15.0-92-generic/kernel/drivers/md/raid10.ko 

can you help this?

Comment: Are you out disk space in /boot or out of RAM? Otherwise try reinstalling it with `apt reinstall linux-modules-5.15.0-92-generic`, and if that does work `apt download linux-modules-5.15.0-92-generic`, then `sudo dpkg --force-all -i <name_of_that_new_deb_file>`

Comment: @DanielT disk space is OK for the VM RAM is still available 1 GB, does this effect with speed process ? also im running the `sudo dpkg --force-all -i linux-modules-5.15.0-92-generic_5.15.0-92.102_amd64.deb`

Comment: I measured that command using cgroups to have a memory.peak RAM usage of `330.39844 MiB`, so it shouldn't be the problem. Are you using RAID? If not, you can try deleting raid10.ko before reinstalling it with that dpkg command. You should also check the disk for errors using `fsck` and `badblocks` (read some answers first to avoid data loss), and your memory with memtest86. Is memory usage or disk usage high (check `htop`) when it gets stuck?

Comment: im not using RAID how do i delete raid10.ko? @DanielT, also the memory usage didnt go high when it gets stuck

Comment: Oh well, just ignore what I said about deleting it. I only said that to try and see if having the file rewritten in a new part of the disk would help. But that is made unnecessary if you do `fsck` and `badblocks`. That should be what comes to mind first because you said "it was failed cus the vm turn off"

Comment: i run `fsck` output `/dev/vda1 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.`

so is should unmount the `/dev/vda1` ? because its mounted on `/ directory`, is it safe tho?

Comment: run badblocks and it says no badblocks `Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)` @DanielT

Comment: You won't be able to unmount /. You need to reboot to the LiveCD, then run fsck on /dev/vda1 there.

Comment: @DanielT alright, i cant do that because i didnt own the VM, but i want to ask , if i keep waiting the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command , does it still has chance to complete?

Comment: It would have a chance to complete if there is still CPU or IO activity going on. Check `htop`, `top` or `iotop` to see if there is any more activity. Also check `dmesg` to see if there are any disk errors being reported. See https://askubuntu.com/a/47974/1004020 to try the /forcefsck option.

Comment: @DanielT also, si there any way to canceled the upgrade? because the kernel im using now is 5.15.0-52-generic so is there any way to canceled the upgrade?

Comment: You could just `sudo killlall dpkg`, then kill related processes. But this may lead to an unbootable system if you don't remove the old GRUB entry. To do that, you could in `dpkg --get-selections | grep 5.15.0-92`, and do `sudo dpkg --force-all -r <list of package names>`. This should at least lead to a bootable system, but `apt` will be broken so you can't install or upgrade until you fix it.